# what exactly does a js.erb file do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a rookie in RoR. I understand the MVC model. The html.erb files are responsible for rendering the view. But what do the the js.erb files do? Are they related only to any jquery that may be present in the view or do they contribute to the overall view as well. Please bear with my naivity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS.ERB (ERB: embedded Ruby) files are standard javascript files. They reside within the view, or app/assets which contains custom JS applicable to the application.

If the JS.ERB file is located with the view folder, it can be referenced by the controller and contain any kind of Ruby on Rails based code.

If the JS.ERB is located with the app/assets folder, it can only reference Ruby code related to the Asset Pipeline, i.e:

```
<%= asset_tag 'image.png' %>
```

This image would reside within app/image, in order for the asset_tag to retrieve the image.

Comment: I have a js.erb file in a view folder. But I am not able to figure out what exactly it is doing. Even when I remove its contents, I cannot see any change in the view. This is the line in js.erb: `$("ul.products").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/product_listing', :locals=>{:collection=> @products})) %></div></div>")`

Comment: js.erb files within the view folder can be called via the controller. The respond_to method within each action can contain js, json and html responses. So when a JS request is sent to the action, it responds with e.g. `format.js { render :partial => 'folder/file', :format => [:js]`. 'folder/file' is the location of your js.erb. The chances are your js is currently not doing anything unless there is a JS request being sent to the views action in your controller. JS requests can be achieved in a number of way, most notably via a `$.ajax '/url/to_action'` or setting :remote => true on a form_for.

Comment: Thank a lot for a detailed explanation. Things are a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller's action will respond with `js.erb` when you do a javascript request. For example ajax request via:

```
link_to '', users_path, remote: true
```

or

```
form_for @user, remote: true
```

Answer (score 0):

ERB is short for embedded ruby, anything with that extension can have ruby code written in it. In rails this is used to dynamically create html, however you can also dynamically create JS files as well. Imagine you had a js.erb file with the following content

```
<% [1,2,3,4,5].each do |i| %>
  alert(<%= i %>);
<% end %>
```

This would render the following javascript:

```
alert(1);
alert(2);
alert(3);
alert(4);
alert(5);
```

Which would result in 5 alerts being shown to the client (not a good idea in practice, but I hope you get the idea)